# "me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow" error when creating online meeting in teams using ms graph api

Tags: laravel, graph

Got access token with given permission online meating read write delegated  but getting this error

> "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow."

i tried in postman https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings with

```
{
    "startDateTime":"2019-09-09T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
    "endDateTime":"2019-09-09T15:33:30.8546353-07:00",
    "subject":"hey",
    "participants":{
        "organizer":{
            "identity":{
               "user":{
                   "id":""
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively sure that something with your api permissions or access token is wrong. I build an entire flow from creation over receive and delete a meeting:

> I used the password flow only for the unit test to get an delegated token

For this tests, you need to add the below K/V in your env:

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=Sup@r5ecurE!
AZURE_USER=test.user@yourdomain.com
AZURE_PASSWORD=Sup@r5ecurE!
```

```php
class GraphMeetingTest extends TestCase
{

    protected function getAccessToken()
    {
        $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . env('AZURE_TENANT_ID') . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
        return Http::asForm()->post($url, [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'username' => env('AZURE_USER'),
            'password' => env('AZURE_PASSWORD'),
            'client_id' => env('AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
            'scope' => 'openid profile offline_access .default',
        ]);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function get_access_token()
    {
        $response = $this->getAccessToken();

        $token = $response->json()['access_token'];

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());

        $this->assertIsString($token);

        return $token;
    }

    /** @test
     * @depends get_access_token
     */
    public function create_online_meeting($token)
    {

        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings';

        $startDateTime = Carbon::parse('08.05.2022 20:29', 'Europe/Berlin');
        $endDateTime = Carbon::parse('08.05.2022 21:29', 'Europe/Berlin');
        $subject = 'User Token Meeting';

        $response = Http::withToken($token)->post($url, [
            'startDateTime' => $startDateTime,
            'endDateTime' => $endDateTime,
            'subject' => $subject,
        ]);

        $this->assertTrue($response->successful());
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('id', $response->json());

        return $response->json();
    }

    /** @test
     * @depends create_online_meeting
     */
    public function get_meeting_by_id($meeting)
    {
        $token = $this->getAccessToken()->json()['access_token'];

        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/' . $meeting['id'];

        $response = Http::withToken($token)->get($url);

        $this->assertTrue($response->successful());
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('id', $response->json());

        return $response->json();
    }

    /** @test
     * @depends  get_meeting_by_id
     */
    public function delete_online_meeting($meeting)
    {
        $token = $this->getAccessToken()->json()['access_token'];
        
        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/' . $meeting['id'];
        
        $response = Http::withToken($token)->delete($url);
        
        $this->assertTrue($response->successful());
    }
}
```